# Preventing FlexiSlider (Adaptive) to resize beyond a certain minimum height

Tags: javascript, theming

I am using Flexi-Slider and AIS to create a responsive (full-width in this case) Images Slider for a front page on a Drupal 7 install.

I got it working perfectly but I would like to restrict the resizing function when the images reach a certain size. Meaning for example, if the height = 500px, even if the device screen size or resolution is smaller than that, or the user resizes the browser window, I don't want the image to get smaller than that.

Is that at all possible? Anyone has done it or could guide me into it? Thank you everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my auto-reponses to the last 3 or 4 questions I posted, serve to the rest :)

Just wrap the block where your flexislider slide views is contained in a div and give it a min-width with !important and set the height to "auto".

Have not tested this in IE yet tho. Let's see.